# Javascript two date time comparision issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, comparison

I am tring to compare two date with javascript.Actually my goal getting warning message if first date is graeter than second date but javascript does not work properly.While i am debugging on firefox cursor going to else block, even if happens condition.Meanwhile, similar javascript code works properly that on jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Mjora/ZNaMW/

**Javascript code**

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    var firstDate = $('#firstDate').val();
    var lastDate = $('#lastDate').val();

    if (firstDate > lastDate) {
        alert("First date can not be greater than Last date!!");
    }
    else{...} 
});
```

Also i tried code like these;

```
   $("#btn").click(function(){
        var firstDate = $('#firstDate').val();
        var lastDate = $('#lastDate').val();

        if (new Date(firstDate) > new Date(lastDate)) {
            alert("First date can not be greater than Last date!!");
        }
        else{...} 
    });

 /********/

var fDate="10.10.2020";
var lDate="10.10.2010";

var fDateSpl= fDate.Split(".");
var lDateSpl= lDate.Split(".");

var newFDate = new Date(fDateSpl[2], fDateSpl[1], fDateSpl[0]);
var newLDate = new Date(lDateSpl[2], lDateSpl[1], lDateSpl[0]);


if (newFDate > newLDate) {
    alert("First date can not be greater than Last date!!");
}
else{...}
```

**Html**

```
<input type="text" id="firstDate"/>
    <br/>
<input type="text" id="lastDate"/>
    <br/>
<input type="button" value="Send" id="btn"/>
```

Comment: String comparison: `if (firstDate > lastDate) {` not dates...

Comment: Yes, does it work if your change it to `newFDate.getTime() > new LDate.getTime()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use Date.parse(firstDate) > Date.parse(lastDate)

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    var firstDate = $('#firstDate').val();
    var lastDate = $('#lastDate').val();
    if (Date.parse(firstDate) > Date.parse(lastDate)) {
        alert("First date can not be greater than Last date!!");
    } 
});
```

[**Fiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/FcefU/)

Comment: I have tried as above but Date.parse() function and getTime() retuns NAN.

Comment: Can you check format of the date you entered ? Or please check format i have used in my fiddle link

Comment: I solved my issue.I sended date as 10.10.2010.I changed dot with slash problem solved.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt `if (firstDate > lastDate) {` fails because it is a string comparrison, not a date comparison.

And your other attempt failed because of a typo

```
var fDateSpl= fDate.Split(".");
var lDateSpl= lDate.Split(".");
```

should be

```
var fDateSpl= fDate.split(".");
var lDateSpl= lDate.split(".");
```

change that and you will have an alert appear